# How to identify a network node that connects more connected subgraphs

Tags: igraph, network-analysis

I've created a network graph, visualized below.

I'm looking for a way to formally identify nodes like the one I've circled. It connects two otherwise more strongly connected sections of the graph.

Can anyone recommend some concepts or associated `igraph` functions that would set me in the right direction? I'm new to network analysis and still lack much of the vocabulary.

[image: network graph]

Answer (score 0):

Use `articulation_points()` and look up *biconnected components*.